# PHP 5.4 associative array giving syntax error

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have a simple associative array declared like the following:

```
static private $foo = [
        16 => 'xyz',
        7 => 'x',
        8 => 'y',
        9 => 'xy'
];
```

When I run a syntax check on this declaration, I get the following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '16' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ']
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing the last single quote  after the 9 => 'xy' and the static and private keywords are the wrong way around.

Comment: sorry that was just a typo when I pasted into here. the single quote is actually there in the real code.

Comment: No worries. Swap static and private so you have `private static $foo`

Comment: Tried that as well @BenSwinburne unfortunately no cigar

Comment: `private static`- `static private` make no difference to the parser ;-) Since this is obviously part of a class definition can you please post a complete script? Try to create the smallest yet complete script possible that exhibits the behaviour you've described.

Comment: Perhaps post a bit more of your code? http://codepad.viper-7.com/0rk42d works using the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the copy/pasted code in any hex editor you'll notice strange invisible characters which are confusing PHP. Just do a clean copy/paste and you are good to go.

And while you are at it, check your editor configuration/encoding.

**EDIT:** A simple Unicode lookup says its the so called [EN SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm) character (hex sequence `E2 80 82`). How you managed to put it in your code is beyond me.

[image]

Comment: It is probably cut-n-pasted from a webpage using css `content`

Answer (score 6):

There are some weird characters (probably BOMs, I wasn't checking it) at the start of each line before an array element (see http://3v4l.org/ZnqIp). These characters are invisible, so their presence can cause strange errors like this one.

They show when pasted into Notepad++ as small squares:

[image: Image showing characters in Notepad++]

I removed them, try this code:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    static private $foo = [
        16 => 'xyz',
        7 => 'x',
        8 => 'y',
        9 => 'xy'
    ];
}
```

It should work just fine (see also http://3v4l.org/WQGWA).

Comment: Nice.  I get ASCII values 226, 128, 130, and 32 for various parts of the whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out with copy&paste your code. For some reason I got the same error. Then deleted all whitespaces in array and again added spaces. Now everything worked out. Have no clue why thats happening. Just try to define array like

```
 private static $foo = [16 => 'xyz', 7 => 'x', 8 => 'y', 9 => 'xy'];
```

And if that works out - add line breaks. Some copy & paste magic is messing up things.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what is going on with your code.  It has nothing to do with static private.

I copied your code above and ran a test and was getting the same parse error. I restructured your array and it seems you added spaces and not tabs.  I'm relatively new to PHP but, I replaced spaces with tabs and it seems to work.

```
private static $foo = [
    16 => 'xyz',
    7 => 'x',
    8 => 'y',
    9 => 'xy'
];
```

Comment: PHP is whitespace-insensitive, except in a few key areas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static $foo = array( 
  16 => 'xyz', 
  7 => 'x', 
  8 => 'y', 
  9 => 'xy'
);
```